# How to change build path on PyDev

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

In eclipse, I'm used to configuring the buildpath for versions of java installed on my computer.

I recently added Python 3.5 to my computer and want to use it in place of the default 2.7 that Macs automatically include.

How can I configure my build path on PyDev, if there is such as concept to begin with, for the plugin? I've found that Python 3.5 is located at`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/`; how can I now change PyDev to use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First check whether python3.5 is auto-configured in eclipse.
Go to **`Window>Preferences`** 
On the preferences window you will find PyDev configurations on left pan.

**`PyDev>Interpreters>Python Interpreter`**

If python3.5 is not listed you can either add using "Quick Auto-Config" or if you want to add manually click "New" then add give the interpreter name (ex:Py3.5) and then browse to the path of python executable (In your case inside `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/`)

Once you have configured your interpreter in PyDev then you can change the interpreter of your project.

Right click on your project>Properties

On the left pan click **PyDev-Interpreter**.In that select the name of the  PythonInterpreter(Py3.5) which you previously configured and you can also select the grammar version.